# Are any natural waxes PH neutral?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I'm a collector of historical artifacts, and one of the most common methods to preserve them is waxing. And one of the best options out there is Renaissance Wax, a microcrystalline wax. The reason it is considered superior to natural options like beeswax is that it is PH neutral, meaning it will not corrode the artifact over time with its acid content.

My only hesitancy to continue using it would be that it is petroleum based. I'm curious if any natural waxes offer the PH neutrality that RW does, as well as being just as long lasting for protecting items from moisture.

Comment: Well, it's "pH" and more proper description would be doesn't contain any significantly acidic compounds, otherwise question seem kinda broad, but oh well...

Comment: Apologies, I'm no chemist.

So how do I check whether a specific ingredient is acidic? And what natural options would there be for waxes without acidity?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beeswax says there's ca 12% of fatty acids in it, not so sure if it's really problem though.

Comment: Petroleum paraffin wax *is* a natural compound. It's been in the Earth a considerable time before mankind was thought of. Yes, it's purified, but so is beeswax (unless you want your beeswax mixed with larvae, honey and bee wastes).